# My While loop ignores user input and always chooses first if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my function to loop back and ask a question again if the user inputs no when asked. Instead of going to my elif statement, it defaults to the first if statement no matter what I put.

```py
def full_name(): # catagorize if user wants to input full name
    try:
        
        while True:
            
            f, n = input("What is the full name? ").split()
            user_confirm = input(f.upper() + " " + n.upper() + ". " + "That's correct? ")

            if user_confirm.lower() == str("yes") or str("y"):
                print("User confirm")
                break

            elif user_confirm.lower() == str("no") or str("n"):
                print("User deny")
                continue
        
    except Exception: print("full name error")
        #pass
    pass
```

Comment: Does it need to be `while True:`?
Can't you make a bool like `isConfirmed = False` and put `while not isConfirmed:`?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance but what would that do? Isn't not False the same as True or am I committing a rookie mistake?

Comment: If you have `isConfirmed = False` and have your `while` loop as `while not isConfirmed`, then if you say `isConfirmed = True` in your first `if` statement, and it will break out of the loop. It seemed to work for me in a repl.

Comment: Hmm alright, I'm going to give this a go on my break and report back. Thank you!